# Open port for public

Tags: networking, nodejs

I have a server that port 9901 is running a application for nodejs.
If i access the app via http://localhost:9901, the apps run successfully.
But if i access the app from external computer and using IP. e.g: http://1.2.3.4:9901. I got error server not responding.

How can i open port `9901` for public?

Comment: you  have to configure port forwarding on your router

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable port forwarding or open the port to the public at the n/w layer(via your router or modem) plus within the O/S also.
For n/w layer please refer to your modem/router user manual and reach out to your ISP(sometimes you need help from ISPs)
For Ubuntu linux or at the O/S layer, you need to refer to [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/firewall.html)

Comment: Assuming, of course, that application is working also on actual network interface, not only loopback - that may also be worth to verify.

Comment: @Jacek i can test the apps working fine from localhost:9901. is that what you mean?

Comment: The question is rather on what interfaces/IPs is your application listening. If only on localhost - you won't access it from outside.